# jinja2 static files mime-type always text/plain

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I have a simple flask application. I have all my css inside `static/css` directory. I have created a master template in which I want to include css from that directory. Following is what I have tried so far.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/justified-nav.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/justified-nav.css') }}" media="screen">
```

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/static/css/justified-nav.css" media="screen">
```

In all the cases the file gets loaded but with **mime-type** `text/plain`. I have tried putting the css file directly into the static folder as well but no results.

What am I doing wrong? How can I include a css file in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask uses the [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) module to determine the MIME type of a file, based on its extension. If you get `text/plain` for a CSS file it means this module returns the wrong MIME type.

On Windows it uses data from the registry, so if the "Content Type" value in `HKCR/.css` is not set to the proper MIME type it can cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it should work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}"/>
```